# Want to create dynamic layout but getting error

Tags: android

I want to create dynamic layout but getting null poniter exception when I add control into view by addview() method.how I solve this error?
this is my xml file

select_theator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/round">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvtheator"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:text="Copperas Cove"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.00"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/seat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/green"
        android:text="SELECT SEATS" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seat"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:text="Share" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp" >
    </RelativeLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:background="@drawable/gray" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tvname"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:text="22 JUMP STREET" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tvdate"
         android:layout_width="50dp"
         android:layout_height="34dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tvname"
         android:maxLines="1"
         android:text="Thu,Jul 10th 11:05 AM" 
         android:textColor="#000000"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/br"
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="20dp"
         android:layout_height="20dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tvdate"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:background="@drawable/round"
         android:text="R" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btime"
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tvdate"
         android:background="@drawable/round"
         android:text="1 hr 50 min." />

     </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my edited  java file
Theator.java

```
public class Theator extends Activity{
    Bitmap bitmap2;
    ImageView iv,iv1;
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    Button bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        sv.addView(ll);


        setContentView(sv);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.select_theator, ll, false);
         iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
         ll.addView(iv);
          tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvname);
          ll.addView(tv1);
          tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
          ll.addView(tv2);
          bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.br);
          ll.addView(bt1);
          bt2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btime);
          ll.addView(bt2);
         tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvtheator);
         ll.addView(tv3);
         iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimg);
         ll.addView(iv1);
          bt3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.seat);
          ll.addView(bt3);
          bt4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
          ll.addView(bt4);
        bitmap2 = getBitmapFromUrl("http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/17/82/11178261_pro.jpg");
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);

    }
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            URL url =new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap mybiBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return mybiBitmap;


         } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
         }


    }


}
```

Comment: post our error log and point out which line is causing null pointer

Answer (score 0):

```
iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
```

findViewById looks for that view in the current view hierarchy, which, in your case, consists only of the ScrollView and the LinearLayout. Use an inflater to retrieve an object of the view that contains the ids you are looking for

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.select_theator, ll, false);
```

and than use

```
iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
```

or you can use directly

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.select_theator, ll);
```

That will add the inflated view inside `ll` and, after you call `setContentView`, you can use `findViewById`, because now, that layout is part of the Activity view hierarchy

Comment: Still getting null pointer exception error at ll.addView(iv) this line

Comment: added edited java file please help me to solve this error as I am new in this concept.

Comment: if you call inflate with the false argument, the inflated view is **not** added to `ll`, and you have to use `view.findViewById`. If you call inflate like `inflate(select_theator.xml, ll)`, the view is added to `ll` and just after that you can use findViewById directly,

Comment: But if I add xml View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(select_theator.xml, ll); like this it gives error so i added like R.layout.select_theator so how I solve this problem?

Comment: my bad, I should have been more precise. I edit the answer. If you have issue, you should also put the error you got

Comment: I am getting this errorjava.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: as I said, the content is added directly to the view, so you do not need to add it again

Comment: what point, did you not get? if you call `inflate(R.layout.select_theator, ll)`, android generates a View object with the content of select_theator.xml and put it inside ll. you can not add twice the same view to the same parent, so if you call addView your application crashes

Comment: I removed ll.addview(iv) and all the line like this error solved but getting blank screen no control is displayed into screen why?

Comment: try putting    `View view = LayoutInflater.from..` before `setContentView`, I'll be back in 1h

Answer (score 0):

You put the line

```
setContentView(sv);
```

after all view has been added.